# TweenJS tweening the frames of a Sprite

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, easeljs, tween

I have a sprite that I want to animate using TweenJS. My first thought was to write something like this:

```
createjs.Tween.get(mySprite).to({currentFrame:30}, 1000);
```

Which didn't work. And simply writing...

```
mySprite.currentFrame = 10;
mySprite.currentAnimationFrame = 10;
```

...does not cause the sprite to update either. So I'm guessing these properties are get only? (`mySprite.gotoAndStop(10);` works just fine.)

Do I need to call an update method of some sort? Or perhaps resort to some `gotoAndStop` hack?

Seems kinda strange that this is a problem. If anyone can shed some light on this it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `currentFrame` property is read-only, though it appears that this isn't being surfaced by the EaselJS docs (it looks like YUIDocs may have broken the `@readonly` tag). It will likely remain read-only for two reasons:

1. We avoid using getter/setters for complex behaviours, which `_goto` is.
2. It would have ambiguous outcomes (is it equivalent to `gotoAndStop` or `gotoAndPlay`?).

One way to work around this, is to leverage the `change` event, something like this:

```
mySprite.frame = 10;
createjs.Tween.get(mySprite).to({frame:30}, 1000).on("change", function(evt) {
   var tween = evt.target, target=tween.target;
   target.gotoAndStop(target.frame);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the docs in GitHub and on the site to show the @readonly flag wherever it is defined in the source.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see where you're coming from. I guess the work around is simple enough anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Well I coulnd't find the functionality I wanted in `Sprite`, so I did this:

```
Object.defineProperty(mySprite, "animationFrame", {
    get: function() {
        return this.currentFrame;
    },
    set: function(frame) {
        this.gotoAndStop(frame);
    }
});
```

Which allowed me to tween like so:

```
createjs.Tween.get(mySprite).to({animationFrame:30}, 1000);
```

Seems kinda hacky to me, but at least it works.

If anyone has a better solution, please do post it!

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the getter/setter which only sent tween values on start and end (null for things between) then created and used a plugin similar to the CSSPlugin

```
/*
 * TweenFramePlugin
 * Visit http://createjs.com/ for documentation, updates and examples.

/**
 * @module TweenJS
 */

// namespace:
this.createjs = this.createjs||{};

(function() {
    "use strict";

    /**
     * A TweenJS plugin for working with frames

     * @class TweenFramePlugin
     * @constructor
     **/
    function TweenFramePlugin() {
        throw("TweenFramePlugin cannot be instantiated.")
    };


// static properties:
    /**
     * @property priority
     * @protected
     * @static
     **/
    TweenFramePlugin.priority = 0; // high priority, should run sooner




// static methods
    /**
     * Installs this plugin for use with TweenJS. Call this once after TweenJS is loaded to enable this plugin.
     * @method install
     * @static
     **/
    TweenFramePlugin.install = function() {
        console.log("TweenFramePlugin installed");
        createjs.Tween.installPlugin(TweenFramePlugin, ["frame"]);
        return createjs.Tween.IGNORE;
    };

    /**
     * Called by TweenJS when a new tween property initializes that this plugin is registered for. Generally, the call
     * to <code>Plugin.init</code> will be immediately followed by a call to <code>Plugin.step</code>.
     * @method init
     * @param {Tween} tween The related tween instance.
     * @param {String} prop The name of the property that is being initialized.
     * @param {any} value The current value of the property on the tween's target.
     * @return {any} The starting tween value for the property. In most cases, you would simply
     * return the value parameter, but some plugins may need to modify the starting value.
     * @static
     **/
    TweenFramePlugin.init = function(tween, prop, value) {
      //  var target = tween.target;
     //   if(!target.hasOwnProperty("currentFrame")){ target.gotoAndStop(value); }
// return the unmodified property value:
        return value;
    };

    /**
     * @method step
     * @protected
     * @static
     **/
    TweenFramePlugin.step = function(tween, prop, startValue, endValue, injectProps) {
        // unused

    };


    /**
     * @method tween
     * @protected
     * @static
     **/
    TweenFramePlugin.tween = function(tween, prop, value, startValues, endValues, ratio, wait, end) {

        tween.target.gotoAndStop(value);
        return tween.target.currentFrame;
    };

    createjs.TweenFramePlugin = TweenFramePlugin;

}());
```

copy that to a file, include it, which needs to be installed sometime on your main html page and 'install' it like so, somewhere after tweenjs has loaded.

```
createjs.TweenFramePlugin.install();
```